# Regularization of loop integrals with Feynman slash

Tags: homework-and-exercises, feynman-diagrams, integration, wick-rotation, dimensional-regularization

As the title suggests, I am trying to compute a loop integral with a Feynman slash in the numerator, like

$$\int\frac{d^Dq}{(2\pi)^D}\cdot\frac{q_\mu\gamma^\mu}{\left(q^2+\Delta+i\epsilon\right)^3}$$

And

$$\int\frac{d^Dq}{(2\pi)^D}\cdot\frac{\left(q_\nu\gamma^\nu\right)\gamma^{\mu}\left(q_\lambda\gamma^\lambda\right)}{\left(q^2+\Delta+i\epsilon\right)^3}.$$

It is pretty obvious, that dimensional regularization should be applied here, but I am not sure how to implement it correctly. Especially talking about the Wick rotation $q_\mu\gamma^\mu$ does not seem to be invariant under rotations.

How does one properly compute such integrals?

Comment: The only part where Dirac matrices matter at all for this is the end where you set $\gamma_\mu \gamma^\mu = D$ instead of 4.

Comment: The Dirac matrices are constants that can be pulled out of the integrals, just like the $1/(2\pi)^D$.